# Promise.defer standard?

Tags: javascript, promise, deferred

I was working with Promises and prefer to use it like this:

```
function Deferred() {
    this.resolve = null;
    this.reject = null;
    this.promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        this.resolve = resolve;
        this.reject = reject;
    }.bind(this));
    Object.freeze(this);
}

function somethingAsync() {

    var deferred = new Deferred();

    // do stuff then deferred.resolve();

    return deferred.promise;
}
```

I just came across though in Firefox `Promise.defer()` which gives me the same thing, is this standard? Or just specific to Firefox? I can't find it in the Promise docs of Firefox even - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/JavaScript_code_modules/Promise.jsm/Deferred) already?

Comment: Thanks @stevenelberger yes I saw that, but that is a wiki edit by a user. I don't trust it, because `Promise.defer` still exists as of Firefox 50.

Comment: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/ -> `ctrl+f` "defer"

Comment: Why do you have the first two lines in your `Deferred()` constructor?  It doesn't seem like they are needed.

Comment: Do not use it, use a promise constructor instead: http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/deferred-migration.html

Comment: @WillemD'Haeseleer - The suggestion in that link is basically no different than what the OP has here.  Pretty much the same thing.  This one uses `new`, the other doesn't.  Other than that, no operational difference.

Comment: Thank you all for the discussion. Thanks @jfriend00 you are correct I actually dont need those two lines nor the bind I should use es6 all the way: `function Deferred() { this.promise = new Promise( (...args) => [this.resolve, this.reject] = args); return Object.freeze(this) }`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Promise.defer` was a suggestion at one point but it was decided to not include it in the spec but to instead include the promise constructor which uses [the revealing constructor pattern](https://blog.domenic.me/the-revealing-constructor-pattern/).

It was implemented in Firefox and Chrome and later removed from Chrome. It is not a standard but was a proposal at one point.

Your usage of the promise constructor was explicitly supported as a use case when it was designed.

The reason the committee decided to go with the promise constructor was because it guards against synchronous `throw`s by default:

```
new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    thisThrowsSynchronously();
});
```

Had the promise constructor not done this - you would have to potentially  `.catch` and `} catch(e) {` on every promise returning function invocation which can be frustrating. The promise constructor establishes an invariant where `.catch` is sufficient.

I'd also like to point out that outside of converting callback APIs - I can count the number of times I've used the promise constructor on one hand. Typically your code should have close to zero deferreds or usages of the promise constructor.

Comment: Thanks Ben for this awesome answer. However jshint warns of creating functions dynamically (within functions on runtime). Is jshint wrong? And that doing so is not bad for performance?

Comment: I'd use an arrow function over `.bind` - your code is generally fine but I honestly don't see why anyone would _want_ to use a defer very much :)

Comment: How does look this look - es6ified! Its so pretty! `function Deferred() { this.promise = new Promise( (...args) => [this.resolve, this.reject] = args); return Object.freeze(this) }` :). Personally I don't have causes for rejection in my async flow currently. So any errors that happen I need to catch it during development. But this combined with the jshint warning of "dont dynamically generate functions for performance" led me to use deferred's in my current projects.

Comment: I think it's good code that solves a problem you shouldn't have :) If you see a scenario where you feel you *need* a deferred by all means feel free to ask about it on this site.